# VScode Remote SSH tunnel failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-debugging, vscode-remote

I am trying to connect on VScode my local computer to an Linux SSH Host which is a server where I don't have root access. I am able to connect in SSH to this server in a terminal but it is not working when I'm doing it on VScode. I got this log message:

```
[12:07:17.157] Log Level: 2
[12:07:17.158] remote-ssh@0.83.2022062315
[12:07:17.158] win32 x64
[12:07:17.165] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+topa", attempt 1
[12:07:17.165] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[12:07:17.165] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"is154":"linux","orcu":"linux"}
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:07:17.166] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[12:07:17.167] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[12:07:17.167] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[12:07:17.167] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[12:07:17.167] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[12:07:17.167] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[12:07:17.179] SSH Resolver called for host: topa
[12:07:17.179] Setting up SSH remote "topa"
[12:07:17.197] Using commit id "30d9c6cd9483b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630" and quality "stable" for server
[12:07:17.199] Install and start server if needed
[12:07:18.612] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[12:07:19.121] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[12:07:19.125] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 51010 "topa" bash
[12:07:19.127] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:07:19.360] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:07:19.360] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[12:07:19.516] > The authenticity of host 'topa (132.167.130.103)' can't be establis
> hed.
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:qVjjnSdv4IIZh3AbQOy94VJIE2bLSV09Im4Gqipbq74.    
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
[12:07:19.517] Detected fingerprint confirmation message
[12:07:19.517] Showing fingerprint confirmation dialog
[12:07:20.871] Got fingerprint response: yes
[12:07:20.871] "install" wrote data to terminal: "yes"
[12:07:20.884] > y
[12:07:20.894] > Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes        
> Warning: Permanently added 'topa,132.167.130.103' (ECDSA) to the li
> st of known hosts.
[12:07:21.150] > herrytan@topa's password: 
[12:07:21.150] Showing password prompt
[12:07:25.053] Got password response
[12:07:25.054] "install" wrote data to terminal: "*************"
[12:07:25.074] > 
[12:07:26.812] > c3eb67dce923: running
[12:07:26.849] > Acquiring lock on /ccc/cont002/home/den/her/.vscode-server/bin/30d9c6cd9483
> b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630/vscode-remote-lock.herrytan.30d9c6cd9483b2cc5866871
> 51bcbcd635f373630
[12:07:26.867] > Found existing installation at /ccc/cont002/home/den/her/.vscode-server/bin
> /30d9c6cd9483b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630...
> Checking /ccc/cont002/home/den/her/.vscode-server/.30d9c6cd9483b2cc58668715
> 1bcbcd635f373630.log and /ccc/cont002/home/den/her/.vscode-server/.30d9c6cd
> 9483b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630.pid for a running server
> Looking for server with pid: 1085201
[12:07:26.956] > Found running server...
[12:07:26.975] > 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products, 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
[12:07:26.984] > Checking server status on port 42983 with wget
> c3eb67dce923: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> DISPLAY====
> webUiAccessToken====
> listeningOn==42983==
> osReleaseId==rhel==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/39011==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> connectionToken==1a11aaaa-a1aa-11a1-a11a-11a111111111==
> c3eb67dce923: end
[12:07:26.984] Received install output: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==42983==
osReleaseId==rhel==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/run/user/39011==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====
connectionToken==1a11aaaa-a1aa-11a1-a11a-11a111111111==

[12:07:26.985] Remote server is listening on 42983
[12:07:26.985] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":42983},"osReleaseId":"rhel","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/39011","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"1a11aaaa-a1aa-11a1-a11a-11a111111111"},"installUnpackCode":""}
[12:07:26.988] Starting forwarding server. localPort 51013 -> socksPort 51010 -> remotePort 42983
[12:07:26.988] Forwarding server listening on 51013
[12:07:26.989] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[12:07:26.990] [Forwarding server 51013] Got connection 0
[12:07:26.992] Tunneled 42983 to local port 51013
[12:07:26.992] Resolved "ssh-remote+topa" to "127.0.0.1:51013"
[12:07:26.997] > 
[12:07:27.001] ------




[12:07:27.014] [Forwarding server 51013] Got connection 1
[12:07:56.998] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 42983: Proxy connection timed out. Is the remote port correct?
[12:07:57.016] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 42983: Proxy connection timed out. Is the remote port correct?
[12:09:34.764] > channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
> channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
```

I saw on google that this problem may be resolved by adding "AllowTcpForwarding yes" on "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" of my SSH Host but I am not sure that this is the same problem and as I said, I don't have root access so I can't edit the sshd_config file.

Could someone enlighten me on the reason for the problem or on a possible solution ? Thanks !